# Flex: setting disabled color of dropdownlist

Tags: user-interface, apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

I would like to disable a  spark drop down list but do not want to have the alpha color over it. I want the color to stay exactly the same. (by user requirements)

I have this code but the disabled color is still the standard disabled color.

mydropdown.enabled = false;
mydropdown.setStyle("disabledColor", 0xFFFFFF);

Am I missing something?

Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DropDownList` is different from `DateField` as it is spark vs mx. So you will want to set a custom `skinClass` for the `DropDownList`.

Create a copy of `DropDownListSkin`, Then remove the `alpha.disabled=".5"` from the top tag.

```
mydropdown.setStyle("skinClass", MyDropDownSkin);
```

---

**Edit Adding an alternative**
You can also wrap the dropdown in a group with the style [`disabledAlpha`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/GroupBase.html#style%3adisabledAlpha) set to 1

```
<s:Group disabledAlpha="1" enabled="false">
    <s:DropDownList />      
</s:Group>
```

Comment: Great thanks a lot Jacob. Thats works really well. So is it true to say with Spark component I have to take the above approach but for mx components I can access individual properties? Or is it just that in this case the alpha.disabled was not accessible?

Comment: The second is more accurate. The alpha.disabled just wasn't exposed by the skinclass. Another option would have been to wrap the dropdown in a group with the style [`disabledAlpha`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/GroupBase.html#style:disabledAlpha) set to 1.